# how to get user name based on id separated by comma in single table

Tags: php, mysql

```
user_id   user_name        user_friend_list
1         dharmendra       2,3,4,5,6,7
2         jitendra         1,3,4,5,6,7
3         xyz              1,2,6,7 
4         pqr              1,3,4
```

now i want to extract user_id & user name based on user_friend_list id 6 i.e
it will return 1,2,3 user_id & user name dharmendra jitendra and xyz.

i simply use splite function of php but it is so complicated  please provide me well shortcut method

thanks & regards

Comment: Please normalize your table design with a user_friend table and your problem will be solved too. It's most time no good idea to store multiple values in just one field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
select user_id, user_name
from your_table
where find_in_set(6, user_friend_list) > 0
```

But it would actually be better to change your table design. Never store multiple values in one column!

Answer (score 0):

first thing the table is not normalized that's why the problem exist 
you must break this table like this or better :)

table 1
user_id
user_name

table 2
user_id
friend_id

table 2 will have some redundant data though which can be removed by adding a third table as a mapping between table1 and table2

now you can have the following query to get the result

**select user_id,user_name from table1 as a join table2 as b on a.user_id=b.user_id where b.friend_id=6;**

Answer (score -1):

"SELECT user_id,username from your table WHERE user_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7)";

Comment: That will return zero rows, that is not how IN works.